Why is the background color of my navbar shrinking and moving left when resizing, regardless of the elements inside?
I have implemented a navbar component in my next js application using the provided navbar.jsx file and accompanying CSS. The navbar is intended to have a black background color (background-color: black;) that spans the entire width of the viewport (width: 100%;). However, when I resize the window, I notice that the background color of the navbar shrinks and moves left, regardless of the elements inside the navbar. Despite setting the width of the navbar to 100%, the background color behaves unexpectedly during window resizing, causing it to not cover the entire navbar as intended. This issue persists even after ensuring that there are no fixed-width parent containers or conflicting CSS rules affecting the navbar's layout. I seek insights into why this unexpected behavior occurs and how to resolve it effectively.
This is my total code
/*Navbar.jsx*/
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { FaFacebook, FaTwitter, FaYoutube, FaSearch } from "react-icons/fa";
import { AiFillInstagram } from "react-icons/ai";
import styles from "./Navbar.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className={styles.navbar}>
        <div className={styles.navitems}>
          <div className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src={"/sixpep-logo.png"} width={170} height={45} />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.menu}>
            <div className={styles.menuwrap}>
              <Link className={styles.menuitem} href="">
                HOME
              </Link>
              <Link className={styles.menuitem} href="">
                ABOUT US
              </Link>
              <Link className={styles.menuitem} href="">
                PORTFOLIO
              </Link>
              <Link className={styles.menuitem} href="">
                BLOG
              </Link>
              <Link className={styles.menuitem} href="">
                CONTACT
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.socialIcons}>
            <i className={styles.socialicon}>
              {" "}
              <FaFacebook />
            </i>
            <i className={styles.socialicon}>
              <FaTwitter />
            </i>
            <i className={styles.socialicon}>
              {" "}
              <FaYoutube />
            </i>
            <i className={styles.socialicon}>
              <AiFillInstagram />
            </i>
            <form action="" method="get">
              <i className={styles.socialicon}>
                <FaSearch/>
              </i>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.button}>
            <button className={styles.orgbtn}>GET A QUOTE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
?/*Navbar.module.css*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
.navitems {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.menu {
  padding: 0 3em;
}
.menuitem,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
.socialIcons {
  padding: 2em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.socialicon {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 0.8em;
}
.orgbtn {
  background-color: #f94c30;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
.navbtn:hover {
  background-color: #b4260f;
}



It would help us to help you if you include a snippet which demonstrates the problem - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
